# got error when install node-sspi on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have ubuntu machine. I want to install the `node-sspi` package.

I got an error: 
`npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for node-sspi@0.2.5: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}}`

What this error means? how to solve it?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi says that it only works on windows only.

Comment: lol this is programming question. I asked about error I had with **package in nodejs**. it's not design question or qa question or product question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-sspi only works on Windows

> NodeSSPI to Node.js is what mod-auth-sspi to Apache HTTPD. In a nutshell NodeSSPI authenticates incoming HTTP(S) requests through native Windows SSPI, hence NodeSSPI runs on Windows only.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi